# Selectively drop digits in mixed-character dataframe

Tags: r, lapply, gsub

I have a dataframe that is 50000x36 and it is structured (please see the image) with many different 1 to 4 digit codes and some Urls.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EbKa.png)

```
|ID|url| # | ###[A-Z] | # | ###[A-Z] | NA | ### |  ...
```

I need to find all 4 digit codes with `###[A-Z]` 
(Where [A-Z] is any one letter; `#` is any digit) and I need to iterate through the DF, converting all `###[A-Z] -> [A-Z]`

```
 df[] = lapply(df, gsub, pattern="^\\d{3}[A-Z]",replacement = "")
```

This will delete all selected entries but at least finds the occurrences.  Does anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: Modified your code a bit: `,lapply(df, gsub, pattern="^(\\d{3})([A-Z])",replacement = "\\2")`, I hope this is what you are expecting. Thanks

Comment: Also, request you not to put images, rather use `dput(head(dataframe,10))` and copy and paste this output for few rows with your question, so that everyone can copy and paste.

Comment: a little less verbose: `df[] = lapply(df, sub, pattern="^\\d{3}([A-Z])",replacement = "\\1")`

Comment: That's embarassingly simple.  Thanks Andre and PKumar!  How does \\1 still "remember" the value to be replaced?

Comment: Also, dput seems far simpler than pictures.  I'll make good use of that.